# Calling WebApi from C# getting exception HttpRequestException

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Below code is a simple ASP.NET website hosted on IIS. When I run the website from local machine it works fine for both environmentName (UAT and SYSTEM). But when hosted on IIS, I get error while calling WebApi for SYSTEM environment and UAT works fine.

```
        string uri = string.Empty;
        StringBuilder sbResult = new StringBuilder();
        string message = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                if (environmentName.ToLower().Contains("system"))
                    uri = "http://172.26.25.53:5453/"; // SYS
                else
                    uri = "http://172.26.129.21:5453/"; // UAT

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri);

                var response = client.GetAsync("api/AppFabric").Result;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

When I run this code for environmentName "UAT", it runs fine. But when environment name is "SYSTEM" I get exception as below

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the
>   remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection
>   attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
>   after a period of time, or established connection failed because
>   connected host has failed to respond 172.26.25.53:5453    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception)

Please help, I am new to WebApi. Is there I am missing something. I have hosted WebApi on both environments in same way.

Comment: is there any firewall blocking sites for restricted access? that can affect your response.

Comment: Try to check `InnerException` from `HttpRequestException` which you get. It can provide you more detailed information.

Comment: But I am able to run the code from local machine Visual Studio, but when I host it on IIS of other server (but same domain as WebAPI servers) then I get exception. I also ran the WebApi for SYSTEM environment on hosted server and it works fine. So, if firewall is an issue on which server I should see, hosted IIS server or WebApi server. Sorry for being naïve but I have just started with all this. Thanks for response.

Comment: Is port 5453 assigned by visual studio? IIS normally runs on port 80. Can you try accessing using "http://172.26.25.53"?

Comment: no the port was assigned by me in IIS as port 80 was taken up by other website.

Comment: can you ping the web api server from the website server. Do a telnet and see if you can really make a call to the server ip and port.

Answer (score 2):

I found this was a timeout problem.
To fix this I increased the connection time in IIS.
In IIS I went to the default website, right clicked --> Manage Website --> Advanced Settings --> Connection Limits (expand) --> change the default from 120 to (say) 180.